# Read just the latest version of delta file on blob storage in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, delta-lake

I have a delta file (consisting of meta data and fragmented parquet files) that I save with databricks to Azure Blob Storage. Later, I am trying to read that file with Azure Data Factory Pipeline but when using copy activity it reads all the data in that delta instead of the latest version (as specified by meta data).

How do I just read one version from delta file on a blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **dataflow** for getting data for specific version.

create a new dataflow activity.

[image]

select **Inline** as source type and **Delta** in inline dataset type.

[image]

Next go to **Source options** tab.
[image]

Here, select your delta **Folder path**, **Time travel** as `Query by version`, then give your version.

This gives you the result.
And use this dataflow in your pipeline.

Comment: I am trying this out and cannot figure out "Time travel Option" How do I make this value dynamic to select the latest version number always ? EDIT: without having manually write the number

Comment: disable `Time travel` default it will take latest version.

Comment: Thanks it did work, but I was supprised it was actually faster to migrate my huge delta file thru databriks pyspark then ADF dataflow!